# Google Action not refreshing access token

Tags: oauth, actions-on-google, google-authentication

The account linking and authentication proces for my google action works just fine, except once the access token expires, it is not being refreshed.

I have the following settings:

- No account creation outside of website
- linking type: OAuth & google sign in
- Flow: Authorization code

OAuth & google sign in client information:

- Entered client id,
- Entered client secret,
- Entered Authorization Url (seems to work just fine as I am able to authenticate)
- Entered Token Url: https://sod.superoffice.com/login/common/oauth/tokens (This is a default url provided by the service I'm authenticating with)

Some additional information about the parameters my external service expects to receive in order to refresh the access token:

```
https://{env}.superoffice.com/login/common/oauth/tokens?
grant_type=refresh_token&
client_id=4ref5376616343b38d14ddcd804f2654&
client_secret=18f45229e442772a78df5f554e24a456&
refresh_token=nKHwerkjh34Yd6QShsnGKk4cFhTwCv3XtJu9PW2X63MtUMygLdI57BJjwCU0&
redirect_url=http://localhost/callback
```

The access token expires every hour and then forces me to relink my Google account with the external service. To me this seems to indicate that the access token is not being refreshed.

Any suggestions...?

Comment: Do you know whether the token endpoint is being called periodically?

Comment: I am not sure how to find out if it is. Google should be responsible for calling the token endpoint to refresh the access token, I don't think I have any control over that part.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing all of the parameters I thought you had to provide at the authorization URL field. Instead of just providing the URL, I also included the parameters such as the redirect url, scope, client id etc.

By just providing the authorization & token URL without any additional parameters I have fixed my issue.